# Extract data with regex

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to extract data from an old website. I have a dropdown list with town names. I am trying to extract town name using regex and insert to the database. I tried `>.*<` but it comes with no match. I am very new to the regex so I don't know what is going on.
Sample data is below. I want the name just before the closing tag.

```
"    <option value=""ABERCROMBIE"">ABERCROMBIE</option>"
"    <option value=""ABERDEEN"">ABERDEEN</option>"
"    <option value=""ABRAMS RIVER"">ABRAMS RIVER</option>"
"    <option value=""ACACIAVILLE"">ACACIAVILLE</option>"
```

Comment: Don't use regex for doing things for which it is not designed.

Comment: "*I tried `>.*<` but it comes with no match.*" (1) you should post code you used which didn't work (2) you should avoid regex here and use proper XML or HTML parser.

Comment: Is this `<option value=""ABERCROMBIE"">` valid html ?

Comment: Are you sure that this old website double `""` to surround attributes like `<tag attribute=""foo"">` instead of `"` or `'` like `<tag attribute="foo">` or `<tag attribute='foo'>`?

Comment: Any particular reason for not using a proper XML/HTML parser?

Answer (score 0):

Your regex is fine but you have to ensure it with a non greedy operator and use capturing groups. You can use this regex.

```
>(.*?)<
```

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/eP3uS3/1)**

```
MATCH 1
1.  [35-46] `ABERCROMBIE`
MATCH 2
1.  [89-97] `ABERDEEN`
MATCH 3
1.  [144-156]   `ABRAMS RIVER`
MATCH 4
1.  [202-213]   `ACACIAVILLE`
```

You can use this code:

```
String line = "<YOUR TEXT TO BE PARSED>";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(">(.*?)<");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line);
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println("Town: " + matcher.group(1));
}
```

Comment: I noticed a downvote, without comment I can't improve the answer

Comment: +1 Just ignore downvoters. There is no other plausible solution.

Comment: @sln thanks man for that. I don't understand why people downvote without reason.

Answer (score 0):

Simply replace everything between `<...>` including ending tag as well using [**Possessive Quantifiers**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html)

sample code:

```
String str="<option value=\"\"ABERCROMBIE\"\">ABERCROMBIE</option>";
System.out.println(str.replaceAll("</?[^>]*+>", "")); // prints ABERCROMBIE
```

**Note:** If needed then call `trim()` to remove leading and training spaces.

[Online demo](http://regex101.com/r/pH8lN6/1)

---

```
<\/?[^>]*+>
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/HrmaqkcYf1kWahUY)